# Can I concatenate "<%# %>" used for databinding in ASP.NET Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table within repeater.
Can I add prefix for this

```
 <tr id="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DocumentId")%>">
```

to something like

```
 <tr id="rowId" + "<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DocumentId")%>">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

User a formatter instead.

```
<tr id='<%# Eval("eDocumentId", "rowId{0}")%>'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<tr id='<%# "rowId" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"eDocumentId")%>'>
```